# Count number of elements in an array

Tags: ksh, array

I would like to ask if there is a way to count the number of elements in an array in `ksh`.

Answer (score 6):

To count the number of elements use
`${#array[@]}`.
In order to get the length of a particular element use (I'm getting the length of the 3rd element)
`echo ${#array[2]}`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [ksh man page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html):

> **${#parameter }**
> If parameter  is * or @, the number of positional parameters is substituted. Otherwise, the length of the value of the parameter  is substituted.